# Visual C++ and SDL not exporting correctly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sdl

My main programming language is c++ and the only ide that has ever worked for me is Visual Studio.  I use SDL for my graphic components and main tick, so as to make my job much easier.  The thing is, though, when I try to export my game and build solutions and stuff, the SDL doesn't get processed with it so when I distribute a game, it doesn't work.  It will often complain about a missing "SDL.dll" even though I specifically test to make sure that it is included.  How do I make it so that SDL will work on other computers?

Comment: Have a look at this link, might help out - http://cplus.about.com/od/programminggames/a/Setting-Up-Visual-Studio-Visual-C-2010-Express-For-Sdl-Development-On-Windows.htm

Answer (score 0):

Zammalad's links is good.  But one more thing I like to do is make sure the DLL is copied into the build directory every time I run.  Then you never have to worry about if the correct DLL (32bit or 64bit) is installed in the system and if it's defined in the PATH.

I have my SDL installed at C:\SDL-1.2.15.  In Visual Studio I do this under properties of the project.

Go to the "Build Events" tab and "Post build event" and add

```
copy /y C:\SDL-1.2.15\lib\x86\SDL.dll "$(OutDir)
```

That's for 32bit for 64bit do

```
copy /y C:\SDL-1.2.15\lib\x64\SDL.dll "$(OutDir)
```

See my comment at 
[Using DLLs in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592870/using-dlls-in-c/15611173#15611173)